# Relationship between Elasticity of substitution of sectoral outputs and elasticity of substitution of inputs

Tags: macroeconomics, production-function, elasticity-of-substitution, ces-function

There are two sectors Y1 and Y2.

Composite output is given by CES form -

[image: Form of Composite good]

Each sector employs Capital and Labor in combination through Cobb-Douglas Production Technology.

The [paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://economics.mit.edu/files/5673&ved=2ahUKEwiuu4-mjsrhAhWLqY8KHe4xBJMQFjACegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0lnH1Lqxau4rHFytXumpD7) mentions that elasticity of substitution between products will be less than one if and only if the (short-run) elasticity of substitution between labor and capital is less than one. They donot provide any motivation behind it. Why should this be true? - Any technical or non-technical explanation will be useful.